# Modules in Project Interpreter are not found when imported Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, python-import

I've created a virtual environment in `Pycharm` and added modules to it through `Settings > Project: > Project Interpreter > + button`.

The project interpreter that is selected holds all the packages I need and its path is `venv\Scripts\python.exe`.

Yet importing the modules I get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Any ideas on what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Open up a terminal window within PyCharm - does it show the venv name in brackets before the prompt e.g `(pipnetv2) D:\Paul\Documents\GitHub\pipnetv2-server>`. If so, do `pip freeze` from the terminal - does it list the expected packages?

Comment: Turns out the python console was configured to a different interpreter. I assumed the console would be configured to the same one.

Comment: @C.Acarbay How did you manage to change the interpreter of the console?